# Wordpress permalinks only for posts

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, friendly-url, permalinks

I would like to use wordpress permalinks but **only** for posts. Is there any way to do that?

I don't care about seo, my website is about niche subject so it already has first position in google. Also enabling permalinks makes some conflicts with plugins I have installed.

I would be completly fine without permalinks but I don't like appearance of post's links - ?p=some_numbers - instead of that I would like something prettier, like post name and date.

How can I achieve that without enabling permalinks? Maybe somehow in .htacces file? But then how do I get post name?

Or maybe I should use permalinks but edit rewrite rules (honestly I have no idea how to do that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into the [Advanced Permalinks plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/)?

Comment: I just checked it and it didn't solve my problem - I still had to enable permalinks for all links not only for posts.

I tried not enabling permalinks in default settings and then setting permalink for posts. Links on my website changed the way I wanted it, but when I open links to posts I get 404.

Comment: did you flush your permalinks? http://vinayp.com.np/how-to-flush-permalink-structure-in-wordpress-when-using-custom-taxonomies-%E2%80%A6or-what-to-do-when-wordpress-custom-taxonomies-show-a-404-page/

Comment: Problem solved, I still had this 404 error but editing .htaccess file helped :)